# how to store datacolumn value in array of double

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I want to draw graph in zed graph , which required `double[] x`, `double[] y`. I want to take value from data column nd put in `double[]x` and `double[]y`.
 `dtarow[0]` value put in `double[] x` , and `datarow[1]` value put in `double[]y`. I get `row[0]` and `row[1]` from store procedure in dataset.

This Is code to get value

```
        DataSet dsGZData = cls.GetDataSP("spReport_GZData_Current");
        DataTable dtGZData = new DataTable();


        dtGZData = dsGZData.Tables[0];
        dgv_GZData.DataSource = dtGZData;

        foreach (DataRow dtrow in dtGZData.Rows)
        {
            foreach (Data Column dc in dtGZData.Columns)
            {
                list1.Add(dtrow[dc]);
                for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
                {
                    lbl_point.Text = list1[i].ToString();

               }

            }          

        }
```

I want this for loop value in `double[] x` and `double [] y`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int i = 0;

foreach (DataRow dtrow in dtGZData.Rows)
    {
        double.TryParse(dtrow[0].ToString(), out x[i]);
        double.TryParse(dtrow[1].ToString(), out y[i]);
        i++;
    }
```